# General non-FEM Galerkin, boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Consider the weak form of our all-time favorite Poisson-equation,
$$- \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot  \nabla v\, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{\Gamma}v \nabla u \cdot  \mathrm{d}x +\int_{\Omega} fv\, \mathrm{d} x,$$
for all test functions $v\in V$ and with some domain $\Omega$, boundary $\Gamma = \partial \Omega$. Please note that the boundary integral does not vanish (yet).

Now, develop the solution $$u= \sum_i \alpha_i \varphi_i$$ (and the rhs $f$) in terms of the basis functions of some Galerkin subspace, $$\mathrm{span}\{\varphi_i\} = V_h,$$
and test with the basis functions to get
$$- \sum_i \alpha_i \int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_i \cdot  \nabla \varphi_j\, \mathrm{d} x =\sum_i \int_{\Gamma}\varphi_j \nabla \varphi_i \cdot  \mathrm{d}x +\sum_i f_i \int_{\Omega} \varphi_i \varphi_j\, \mathrm{d} x$$
for all $j=1, \dots , N$.
Introduce the matrices $S$, $M$, with
$$S_{ij} = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_i \cdot  \nabla \varphi_j\, \mathrm{d} x $$
$$M_{ij} = \int_{\Omega} \varphi_i \varphi_j\, \mathrm{d} x$$
Now one can proceed to write this in matrix-vector form,
$$A\alpha = Mf + \sum_i \int_{\Gamma}\varphi_j \nabla \varphi_i \cdot  \mathrm{d}x$$ and solve for $\alpha_i$, as known. However, the boundary term has to be handled yet.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume homogeneous Dirichlet-BC on $\Gamma$. Usually, one would then set the test and trial space as $H^1_0(\Omega )$, that is one would require the basis functions to already satisfy the BCs. My questions now:

1. Is this necessary? I've tried to derive a matrix similar to $S$ and $M$, but it's really non-trivial to impose the BCs on the solution $u$, if the basis functions do not satisfy them.
2. Is there any good literature on both, theory and implementation, of these kind of general Galerkin-methods, where the basis function are **not** FEM-basis functions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I've understood you correctly :/ Do you mean that, given non-homogeneuous Dirichlet-BC, the basis function on the boundary don't vanish?

Comment: I suppose this is the case. I tried to solve Newton's equation for a free particle. Finally after some trials, I obtained a singular S matrix, meaning there is a degree of freedom, namely the initial speed if one fixed an initial Dirichlet BC, but no condition at the endtime.

Comment: Btw what if $\Omega$ were considered a variable ? Shouldn't integration constants be taken into account in $\int_0^T\phi_n(t)\phi_m(t)dt+C$, since the derivative of C is 0 ?

Comment: I think we can neglect inhomogeneous Dirichlet BCs for now, because you can transform it into the homogeneous case when solving with FEM. 
So you tried to solve time-dependent problems? Wouldn't you usually just use FDM for the time variable and solve space-problem with FEM? I think the purely elliptic case is not completely clear yet. At this point, however, I think that it is necessary to impose the Dirichlet BCs on the basis functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The boundary condition can be interpreted as a constraint on the more general solution space. There are many approaches to apply Dirichlet-type constraints: penalty methods, Lagrange multiplier methods, augmented Lagrangian methods, Nitsche's method.
2. The theory is very similar up to some point, e.g. the best approximation property (Cea's lemma) holds in many cases. However, to get a priori error estimates depending on the number of degrees-of-freedom (or mesh parameter as in FEM) you typically combine best approximation property with interpolation theory and this is a very well known topic in the context of FEM basis functions.

Now it depends on the actual basis whether you have interpolation estimates available in the litetature or not. E.g. for many spectral-type bases (sine/cosine, orthogonal polynomials) you can find the relevant theory.